# How to edit tabular data (ASP MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-table

I need to be able to edit a table of data in the browser.

I have seen in MVCContrib there is a HTML helper to render out a table. Useful... but what about if I want the user to be able to edit that table? From what I can see it does not help there.

What is the best way to approach this?

Traditional FORM with a TABLE inside? If so is MVC smart enough to parse the posted data back into a collection of rows? How would that work anyway?

Or perhaps it should just switch to edit mode when a row is clicked (using javascript etc) then when user moves to a different row an AJAX action is called to submit just the one row. I can imagine the logic could get complex here - this would presumably still use a form but would I have to insert it into the DOM dynamically?

I also need to be able to add rows to this table. I do not require paging support.

Is there an off the shelf solution out there?

Should I go back to web forms? :)

Comment: see http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: cant quite figure out how this saves data back to the system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at Phil Haack's blog where he describes how to [model bind to a list](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).

Maybe this can help?

Comment: interesting article. shows potential but claims to be out of date. also this is a low level solution - i was hoping for something more shrink wrapped

Comment: How about this solution using jQGrid:
http://ericdotnet.wordpress.com/2009/05/02/editing-in-jqgrid-with-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: ill accept this as the answer as its as far as I got. My mistake was thinking anything UI of sophistication could be accomplished on the web that was not a hack! HTML was never meant for this...

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same problem, and I have found a solution for it. Don't think it's the most beautiful, but it's ideal for me, because one of my requirements was be able to edit table data using jQuery's [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugin.

So I generate a table using MVCContrib's Grid<> extension:

```
Html.Grid<Somenamespace.Line>( Model.InvoiceLines )
           .Attributes( id => "InvoiceGrid" )
           .Columns( column => {
               column.For( li => li.LineItem.ItemDescription ).Attributes( name => ".LineItem.ItemDescription", @class => "click" );
               column.For( li => li.LineItem.InvoiceUnitNetPrice ).Named( "Unit net price " ).Attributes( name => ".LineItem.InvoiceUnitNetPrice", @class => "click" );
               column.For( li => li.LineItem.InvoiceQuantity ).Attributes( name => ".LineItem.InvoiceQuantity", @class => "click" );
           })
           .Render();  
//rest of the code
Html.Submit("_submit", "Save");
```

Right now You can edit in place values, but it doesn't upgrade corresponding model. 
All the magic happens after user clicks submit button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#_submit').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#InvoiceGrid tbody tr').each(function(index) {
                    var hidden = $('<input />').attr({ type: 'hidden', name: 'InvoiceLines.Index', value: index });
                    $(this).children('td:first-child').before(hidden);
                    $(this).children('td:not(:first-child)').each(function() {
                        $(this).append($('<input />').attr({ type: 'hidden', value: $(this).text(), name: 'InvoiceLines[' + index + ']' + $(this).attr('name') }));
                    });
                });
                $('form').submit();
            });

            //editable stuff            
            $('.click').editable(function(value, settings) {
                return (value);
            }, { submit: 'OK' });
        });
```

In every TD I create hidden input, with value from that TD, in every row input with Index, and the most important here is 'name' attribute: *Name of collection in Model[here goes index].rest.of.path*, so in this particular case (example):

```
InvoiceLines[2].LineItem.ItemDescription
```

Hope it'll help, because rich grid isn't always an answer ;)

Regards
Mateusz

Answer (score 1):

I would checkout one of the javascript UI libraries first:

- [ExtJS Grid](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html)
- [Yahoo DataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_cellediting.html)
- [Flexigrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/)

WebForms are easier when it comes to quickly developing rich UI's like editable grids.

Comment: Thanks.

Flexigrid does not appear to support editing yet.
Yahoo DataTable looks basic which is fine, but I can't see how you save data back.
ExtJs - I just discovered this. Looks good (*too* complex?). Investigating now

Answer (score 0):

Last night I implemented a simple solution: form + table inside, using input fields in the cells with naming convention as described in [Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) (thanks to @BengtBe for link).

It's working but its a bit fiddly (e.g. adding rows with jquery requires me to work out the next unused index).

So I am still looking for more solutions.

One I have discovered is the [extjs library](http://extjs.com) which provides a very rich grid. I have yet to work out whether there is an easy way to post back the grid data to one of my controller actions yet though...