# Add data to different tables using same view and controller in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am new to asp.net mvc4 and creating a project in it. I am stuck on the way.

First let me describe about my project. I am creating a product table and each product has some attributes. I have created a **ProductAttribute** Model and a **AttributeValue** Model to add attributes and their values. Then I have created a **ProductAttributeValue** Model to assign the attributes and their values to the Product.

Now my problem is that I want to use the same view to add Attribute and their values. Below are my models:

```
[Table("ProductAttribute")]
public class ProductAttribute
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string AttributeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Attribute Name")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Datatype")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string AttributeDatatype { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Is Active")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Attribute Type")]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string AttributeType { get; set; }
}

[Table("AttributeValue")]
public class AttributeValue
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]        
    public string AttributeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string AttributeVal { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductAttribute ProductAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

How can I insert values to different tables using one view and controller? If there is another way to do the same then please help me about that.

Thanks

Comment: just to clarify,  are you trying to populate multiple tables on the same view with different parts of the model that is being passed to the view?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to insert data in two tables from the same view. what I want is a user can create a new attribute and at the same time he can enter values for the attribute and save both of them on one submit click. Is this possible in MVC4 as I can do this easily in asp.net. But have no idea in mvc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are getting at.  First you are going to want to build a View Model.  Something like

```
public Class Tables
{
    public List<ProductAttribute> Products { get; set; }
    public List<AttributeValue> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Set those lists from your controller and pass them to the view.  On the view you will define the model like

```
@model Tables
```

and then in the view build your table in your manner of preference.  I have used Html.WebGrid in the past but have been using just foreach loops recently

```
<table>
foreach(var temp in Model.Products)
{
     <tr>
         <td>
               temp.Name, etc
         </td>
     </tr>
}
</table>
```

as for adding and creating I have never been a fan of creating or adding directly in the table and generally what I am showing in the table isn't all of the information that I want from them so I use context menus or edit buttons on the rows and then a add button in a context menu or just outside of the table that will redirect to an edit/add page and then navigate back.  Then you can refresh the table with a post back, jquery, refresh a partial view,  whatever way fits your situation best.  Hopefully this helps :)
Oh,  here is a link to people discussing best how to edit a table
[How to edit tabular data (ASP MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901509/how-to-edit-tabular-data-asp-mvc)

Update:
Any information passed to the view through the model and used on the page with a for (html.textboxfor, textareafor, etc) will be passed back to the controller.  If those fields are changed then the changed value will be passed back.

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    (build your table class)
    return View(Tables);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Tables tbl){
     (pass values return from the view to your query for saving to the database)
{
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems your code will show the values on the view but I want to save the values entered in the view to the database tables. How can I do this?